# Regular Expression for javascript to validate name and version

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to write a regular expression in JavaScript. I need to validate name and version, with the following conditions:

Name:

- Only alphabets, No numbers and special characters
- No trailing spaces at start or end, and no multiple spaces between words.
- Minimum of 3 and Maximum of 50 characters.

Version:

- Format should be `[number].[number].[number]`
- Only a single dot between numbers (`1.3..4` is invalid, `1.3.4` is ok)
- Each number can be of 1 or 2 digits, like `1.11.26`(valid), but not `2.343.23` (Invalid)

Comment: No effort shown. SO is not a free code writing service (though apparently some people think it is!)

Comment: Hello user, and welcome to Stack Overflow! Obviously, we would like to see your failed attempts in resolving this problem, and some valid/invalid sample strings - this will certainly help in getting a good answer. If you have had a positive experience here at Stack Overflow, please tell all of your friends.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Name**

The regex

```
^(?! )((?!  )(?! $)[a-zA-Z ]){3,50}$
```

- Only alphabets, No numbers and special characters => We use a character class for that

  ```
  [a-zA-Z]
  ```
- No trailing spaces at start or end, and no multiple spaces between words. => By "anchoring" the regex we say that it should be the only thing on the line and it can't partially match. With negative lookahead we say that more than 2 spaces are not allowed

  ```
  ^...$
  (?!  )
  ```
- No spaces at beginning and and end => Again we can use some lookaround

  ```
  ^(?! )...(?<! )$
  ```

  but since javascript doesn't support lookbehind we have to use lookahead

  ```
  (?! $)[a-zA-Z ]
  ```
- Minimum of 3 and Maximum of 50 characters.

  ```
  {3,50}
  ```

**Version**

The regex

```
^\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}$
```

- Format should be [number].[number].[number]

  ```
  \d+\.\d+\.\d+
  ```
- Only a single dot between numbers (1.3..4 is invalid, 1.3.4 is ok) => By specifying \d we say that only digits are allowed followed by a dot (which should be escaped since otherwise it will mean any character)
- Each number can be of 1 or 2 digits, like 1.11.26(valid), but not 2.343.23 (Invalid)

  ```
  \d{1,2}
  ```

The last regex becomes the following in javascript

```
if (/^\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}$/.test(subject)) {
    // Successful match
} else {
    // Match attempt failed
}
```

Comment: Hey actually i m new to regex.I dont need multiple spaces that is working but its not accepting even single space like rahul malhotra.so what should be the change in the regex?

Comment: @sanjay Updated my answer by adding some lookahead

Comment: BTW It's okay you are new to regexes but mention this in the question itself. Its rare you don't have any clue how to start but it's possible as this is a pretty advanced question.

Comment: Hey..updated regex is accepting trailing space at start or end. My requirement is:
Valid : "Rahul", "Rahul Sharma", "Rahul Kumar Sharma"
Invalid : " Manoj", "Manoj ", "Manoj  Modi"

Comment: @sanjay Update my answer. Some lookaround solved it.

Comment: This is an amazing explanation of regular expressions!